# get metadata from jpg, dng and arw raw files

Tags: c++, image, metadata, dng

I was wondering if anyone new how to get access the metadata (the date in particular) from jpg, arw and dng files.

I've recently lost the folder structure after a merge operation gone-bad and would like to rename the recovered files according to the metadata.

I'm planning on creating a little C++ app to dig into each file and get the metadata.

any input is appreciated.

( alternatively, if you know of an app that already does this I'd like to know :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, so I did a google search (probably should have started with that) for "batch rename based on exif data arw dng jpg"

and the first page that popped up was the ExifTool by Phil Harvey
it supports recent arw and dng files, and with some command line magic I should be able to get it to do what pretty much what I want

```
exiftool -r -d images/%Y-%m-%d/%Y%m%d_%%.4c.%%e "-filename<filemodifydate" pics
```

-move files to folders (images/YYYY-MM-DD/) and rename files to YYYYMMDD_####.ext that are in pics folder(and subfolders)

hope this helps others

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked at the libexif project http://libexif.sourceforge.net/?

Answer (score 0):

You should also try Adobe XMP SDK, which is great for its supported formats (JPEG, PNG, TIFF and DNG).